# Service Scope as Singleton in grails3

Tags: grails

Reading form this http://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/ref/Services/scope.html

and By default services are "singleton",

So Does Grails automatically lock/Synchronize the service object if the scope is a singleton?

in case many requests using the same service a

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

> By default services are "singleton",
>
> So Does Grails automatically lock/Synchronize the service object if
> the scope is a singleton?

No.  Grails configures Spring to create a single instance of your service and inject that instance everywhere it needs to be injected.  In general services don't need to be synchronized if they are stateless but if you are doing something that calls for synchronization, do that.